# How to prevent non-ascii character turn weird from html form input

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

When user submit his name as

Thorsten Löhrlein

I am getting this

Thorsten Lï¿œhrlein

It is not happen on my computer thought when I submitting my name as Löhrlein, but is there any technique to prevent the character turn weird in all case ?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating this and check it in your HTML page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I already had that in my page, most of case it work but sometime it didn't